# How to refresh the Spring context when using CXF?

Tags: spring, cxf

We have a web application that uses Spring (3.0.5) and CXF (currently 2.4.2 for various reasons but upgrading is an option if that makes any difference) and is deployed on Tomcat.

The application is initialized using the *org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener*.

Starting and shutting the application down works like a charm but if I try to refresh the Spring application context, using

`((ConfigurableApplicationContext)applicationContext).refresh();`

I run into problems. The application context first destroys all its beans (including *CXFBusImpl*, or rather its subclass *SpringBus*). SpringBus however calls close() on its application context - leading to a NullPointerException when the application context shortly after tries to close its bean factory:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.closeBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:152)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:124)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:467)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:397)
```

Is there anything I can do to avoid this (other than modifying CXF)? If I skip CXF everything works.

Comment: Why are you refreshing the context?

Comment: I have a quite complex application that sometimes needs to be reconfigured (without restarting Tomcat) after the configuration has changed. It works, apart from the CXF issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can tell CXF not to work that way. What you could do though is to isolate the parts of your application that need restarting into their own context that you build and and tear down as you choose without involving the main context over much. Perhaps you'd do that with a [`ClassPathXmlApplicationContext`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/support/ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.html), though there are a few choices. I *think* you'll be setting the outer context as the parent of the inner, and referring to outer beans with [XML-config syntax](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-ref-element) like:

```xml
<ref parent="foo" />
```

You'll then need to create some way of proxying the activity with CXF in the outer context to the beans in the inner context. This is the tricky part, as it is usually considered bad form for references to go that way round. You'll probably have to have some kind of registry/proxy in the outer context that (relevant) inner beans connect to as part of their creation/init process (and deregister from at tear-down). You'll also have to decide how to handle the case where a request needs to be served when there is no inner context. Tricky, especially if you want to do it elegantly...

Comment: Yes, something like that would probably work. I had a look at it yesterday but it seems strange for something that should "just work" (assuming that my beans can be initialized and destroyed properly). I think I'll file this as a bug on CXF.

Comment: CXF-4094 is resolved in CXF 2.4.7 and 2.5.3. However, in order for it to fully work the CXFServlet needs to refresh itself as well. I have filed a bug on this (https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CXF-4127) but one can easily create a custom subclass until it gets resolved.